# Very slow HTTP response from Azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, azure, apache2

I'm relatively new to Azure and migrated our backend API to Azure ubuntu server.

The current size of our Ubuntu VM is Standard DS2 v2 and it only has Apache2.4 installed which is running our PHP code.

It was fine on the first day after migrating. HTTP request was flowing in and out normally until yesterday, we've notice that HTTP request was responding very slow. A very simple request takes roughly  [30 sec to 2 min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOKjd.png), sometimes 522 returned.

FTP & SSH are working perfectly fine and the [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAR1r.png) response is good too.

Tried Stopped the VM overnight (8 hours), it was fine for first 3 hours and it went back to the same state over again. Restarting and Stopping & Starting wouldn't solve the issue.

I have no idea on how to solve this, maybe someone can shed some light/share/guide me on how can I troubleshoot this issue.

Extra information:

[Network security group settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bpq8.png)

[Data of VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmVoX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. Replying here just in case anyone needs help.

Apparently it was the coding problem making a lot of unnecessary DB queries, slow HTTP response are due to DB are flooded with queries and waiting the turn to execute their own DB queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add SSD
2. enable accelerated networking azure
3. check ping response is latency there

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tips.
1. our VM is alrdy running on premium SSD
2. will definitely try when the server is less busy, as i search around the internet it requires of reattaching the NIC. Will update you on this.
3. I dont really get this but as per the screenshot posted above the ping response is good i would say.